# get clicked element ID or Name jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wants to get the ID or the name of the clicked elemt by using the following code. this code is working fine if i have only one element.

```
        $(window).mousedown( function(e) {
            mouseTracker.clickState = true;
            console.log( "id:" + e.target.id + " name:" + e.target.name );
        }).mouseup( function() {
            mouseTracker.clickObject = '';
        });
```

but if element is wrapped up in other elements then i am unable to get the ID. for example:

```
 <div id="main"> 
     <div id="subDiv"> 
            <span id="spID" onClick="alert ('hello world')"> Click Me </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

in the above case, it is return the ID of the main div. how can i get the clicked element.

Comment: You're getting the ID of the clicked element, no doubt about it, as that's what `event.target` is, the element you clicked.

Comment: Here's to confirm what @adeneo said: http://jsfiddle.net/yst625y3/

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to do this is to add an event listener to each element. There are different ways to do that:

First as you have coded in your HTML:

```
var testfunction = function(event){
    // Do something
};
<span id="spID" onclick="testfunction(event)"></span>
```

Or nicer:

```
<span id="spID"></span>

var element = document.getElementById('spID');
element.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // do something
})
```

Best regards

Dustin

Comment: That is a terrible solution.

Comment: Before you criticise you have to present a better solution! Maybe you need to read some JavaScript Beginners Tutorials and continue with some best practise guides.

Comment: It's been years since I've read a beginner's JS tutorial, you might be right. As far as the solution goes, OP's code works fine, read the top two question comments.

Comment: I got your comment the first time. Anyway, why is your solution terrible: imagine having tons of overlapping elements, imagine you have to dynamically add more elements... How long would the browser survive? How much repeated code will you have to write? That may or may not be mentioned in beginner's tutorials... And the most important part: **relax**, it's nothing personal, I just think that code is a bad solution for this question for the reasons explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use inline scripting if it was me. The bigger a project gets, the messier this becomes. I tend to have all my event listeners tucked away together in an init function that you can just add to as you need more event listeners:

In the `head` of your HTML:

```
<script src="global.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        global.init();
    });
</script>
```

In a separate js file, linked to your HTML (e.g. `global.js`):

```
(function (global, $, undefined) {

    global.init = function() {
        //bind your event listeners in here
    };

})(window.global = window.global || {}, jQuery));
```

In terms of using this for the purposes of what you are trying to do, if you have a series of these clickable spans, I would use a class selector, so you only have to bind the click event once, otherwise if you are binding to only one span as above then you already know the ID anyway as you had to use it in the bind.

Using class:

```
global.init = function() {

    //assuming you have applied the class "clickable-span" to all the spans you want to be clickable
    $('.clickable-span').on('click', function(evt) {

        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
            name = $(this).attr('name');

        console.log( "id:" + id + " name:" + name );

    });

    //add more event listeners here

};
```